# How to put a linebreak after the User Input has reached the end of a Textbox?

Tags: html, css, input

I know this question has been asked but I cant find the solution to it.

This is my tag :

```
<input type="text" id="userText" class="userTextBox">
```

and this is my css :

```
  .userTextBox {
    /* Add some margin below the input element */
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
  }
```

but overflow-wrap or word-wrap dont work.

I tried overflow-wrap,word-wrap and word-break. But they dont work.

Comment: inputs are inline-elements and only allow a single line input. If you looking for a multi-line input you need to use `textarea` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input>` is an inline element and as such also only allows a single-line text. If you need a multi-line text input you need a block-level input which is called `textarea`. It does exactly what you try to do by default:

```css
.userTextBox {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  
  /* disables the default resize ability */
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="userText" class="userTextBox"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` is a single line text input.
But `<textarea>` is a multiple line.

Here you only need to change the  to  in html.

`<textarea id="userText" class="userTextBox"></textarea>`

And in css remove `overflow-wrap: break-word;` and if you don't need to add the feature to resize, you can add `resize: none;`